# How to redirect users if they enter domain IP instead of domain name

Tags: .htaccess

My site for example named `example.com` and IP Address for it is `12.12.12.12` .

All whats I need is when some one enter IP Address instead of the domain name the server must redirects the user to site with its name not IP address.

In other word, when some one enter `12.12.12.12` the server must open site with its domain name `example.com`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple.
Put this code in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^12\.12\.12\.12$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```